# How to use not exist in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive

I am new to hive sql.It does not support "not exist in" function.

How we can achieve that

If my tables *"T1"* has values **a,b,c,d,e** and  table*"T2"* has **z,b,g,d,e**

my expected output was **a,c**.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.columnName
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
ON (t1.columnName = t2.columnName)
WHERE t2.columnName IS NULL
```